# dompdf isn't working in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I have make a html view page for generate to a pdf report from this view and i have also installed dompdf library, i have loaded data from database table on this view and create a hyperlink name as Download pdf. but when i click on this link it's show undefined variable ***dsale*** error.

here  my controller method.

```
 //pass data to view
public function dsreport($id,$fromdate,$todate)
{
    $dsale=DB::table('directsales')
            ->join('clients','directsales.client_id','=','clients.id')
            ->join('products','directsales.product_id','=','products.id')
            ->select('clients.client_name','clients.addr','directsales.*','products.name')
            ->where('directsales.client_id','=',$id)
            ->whereBetween('directsales.issue_date',[$fromdate,$todate])
            ->distinct()
            ->paginate(3);
            //->get();
        $sumt=DB::table('directsales')
            ->where('directsales.client_id','=',$id)
            ->sum('directsales.total');

    return view('reports.directsalereport',compact(['dsale','sumt']));
}

//generate pdf
public function dsalepdf()
{
    $pdf=PDF::loadView('reports.directsalereport');
    return $pdf->download('dsread.pdf');
}
```

Here is my view part.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <center><h1><strong>M/s. Priti Enterprise</strong></h1></center>
    </center>
    <center><h2><i>Daily Sales Report</i></h2></center>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Client Name: {{$dsale[0]->client_name}}</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Delivered by: {{$dsale[0]->deliverd_by}}</strong></div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Client address: {{$dsale[0]->addr}}</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Date: {{$dsale[0]->issue_date}}</strong></div>
    </div><br><br>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <th class="col-md-1">SL no.</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Invoice no.</th>
            <th>Unit per ctn.</th>
            <th>Unit price</th>
            <th class="col-md-2">Sales</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($dsale as $d)
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>{{$d->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$d->transaction_code}}</td>
                <td>{{$d->unitperctn}}</td>
                <td>{{$d->unitprice}}</td>
                <td>{{$d->ctn}} ctn {{$d->pcs}} pcs</td>
                <td>{{$d->total}}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="col-md-11"></div>
    <div class="row"><strong>Total:{{$sumt}}</strong></div>
    <div>{{$dsale->links()}}</div>
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <a href="{{route('downpdf')}}" class=" btn btn-info"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Download PDF</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Comment: and post this view code `reports.directsalereport`

Comment: @Gabrielle is your problem solved? :)

Answer (score 3):

You have an array in `compact`.

You should use `<div>{{$dsale[0]->links()}}</div>`.

I think you should dont compact an array.

```
return view('reports.directsalereport',compact('dsale','sumt'));
```

**Edited:**
You should pass data to your Pdf view,  too, so your method for downloading pdf should look like this.

```
public function dsalepdf()
{

    $dsale=DB::table('directsales')
                ->join('clients','directsales.client_id','=','clients.id')
                ->join('products','directsales.product_id','=','products.id')
                ->select('clients.client_name','clients.addr','directsales.*','products.name')
                ->where('directsales.client_id','=',$id)
                ->whereBetween('directsales.issue_date',[$fromdate,$todate])
                ->distinct()
                ->paginate(3);

            $sumt=DB::table('directsales')
                ->where('directsales.client_id','=',$id)
                ->sum('directsales.total');

    $pdf=PDF::loadView('reports.directsalereport',['dsale' => $dsale,'sumt'=> $sumt]);
    return $pdf->download('dsread.pdf');
}
```

Comment: i'm try this things, but still now show the error **Undefined variable: dsale**

Comment: @Gabrielle please dd($dsale,$sumt) before return.

Comment: @Gabrielle dont forget to pass your data into pdf view

Answer (score 0):

You may need to delete the vendor folder, then run composer install